# VBA in Word 2013 with TableOfContents Object issue

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to update my Table of Contents in one of my macros after I edit a bunch of stuff. I'm running into an odd issue though. Below is the snippet I was running.

Note: user_document is declared globally as a Document object. It is accessible in this function.

```
Private Sub RunBuild_Click()
    Dim TOC As TableOfContents
    With user_document
        For Each TOC In .TableOfContents  'ERROR OCCURS HERE
            TOC.Update
        Next
    End With
    user_document.Save
End Sub
```

When I run this, I get an object doesn't support this property or method error. I can't seem to figure out why I can't access the TableOfContents object in this document through a loop. The For Each block is supposed to enumerate the collection of objects so I can loop them, but it's acting like this concept doesn't exist. I've seen other posts for updating all Table of Contents that use this exact type of loop and have no issues.

If I use the line

```
user_document.TableOfContents(1).Update
```

The command runs perfectly fine. However, this doesn't allow me to catch the situation that no TOC exists or when multiple exists, it will only update the first instance.

Any ideas? I'm stumped. I keep rewriting the loop and trying different ways to access the object but they all throw the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit1:** My Bad. Your code should work if you write it like this:

```
Dim TOC as TableOfContents ' without s on Table

With user_document
    For Each TOC In .TablesOfContents ' with s on Table
        TOC.Update
    Next
End With
```

But below should work as well just fine.

```
Dim i As Long

With user_document
    For i = .TablesOfContents.Count To 1 Step -1
        .TablesOfContents(i).Update
    Next 
End With
```

This is assuming `user_document` is a document object properly set.

Comment: This is one of those facepalm moments. I just noticed that the reason why I kept having trouble with the damn object auto-completing was because it's called "TablesOfContents" and not "TableOfContents"

I'm getting a new error now, but at least it's related to my code and not my method. I'll update when I sort out the new error.

Comment: @nosjojo Haha Yeah I noticed that as well. Edited my code. I was accustomed to how Excel handle its parent and child objects and Word has some difference.

Comment: Your new edit is pretty much exactly what I got after sorting my other error out. I went ahead and marked yours as the answer and posted my own answer with my updated code. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out.

The TOC object I declared is of type "TableOfContents", but the Document Object contains a TablesOfContents object with individual TableOfContents objects inside.

The following code correctly loops through the structure.

```
Private Sub RunBuild_Click()
    Dim TOC As TableOfContents

    With user_document
        For Each TOC In .TablesOfContents
            TOC.Update
        Next
    End With

    user_document.Save
End Sub
```

This also explains why i had trouble without getting a more meaningful error - I was accessing valid objects incorrectly instead of invalid objects correctly. Since word wasn't fussing about the object being invalid, I didn't even think to check the object for singular/plural naming.